# VB.Net - Are Windows Forms Allowed in Classes?

Tags: vb.net, forms, programmatically-created

Hello once again StackOverflow community!

I have a fairly simple questions but surprisingly I am unable to find this answer while using google for the past hour...

Question is: Can you create a Form inside a Class Library, or in other words can I have my DLL(Class Library) create a form programmatically?

I am working on a Updater for a application a few friends and I use and I constantly find myself making small changes and tweaks in the code the more we use it so it would be nice to be able to update it with less effort on my part.

Comment: Yes you can. Just make sure you have a reference to System.Windows.Forms inside your class library.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! @FloatingKiwi